# How to use Apache Nifi to transfer lots of data (GB) without memory error?

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, apache-nifi

I am using apach NiFi to transfer the base in postgres to bigquery, but, some tables are lot of big (29GB) and  I am receiving memory erro of the VM. can i jump this limit? i need do upgrade in my descktop to suport this transition? or exist outher way to do?

error: java.lang.outofmemoryerror: gc overhead limit exceeded

schema: [imageSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3owM.png)

Comment: First - you have to provide more info about environment. Memory available on your computer, memory (-xmx parameter) reserved for nifi, which processor is failing, full error message with stacktrace from nifi log file.

Comment: Hi @daggett, thanks for answering. I am begin in the tool and i don't know like use 100%, but, i read about and find that the VM JAVA have memory limit. I tryed with 290 MB and passed of the limit, but with 130 MB it worked, so, the virtual machine it must have something between this values. 
my computer has 8 GB ram. I need use this tool or outher to pass big amount of the data.

Comment: please answer all questions - then maybe someone could help you

Comment: Hi @dagget! I writed the error and add how i doed scheme in nifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Auto Commit` property to `false` when executing queries for big `PostgreSQL` tables because the driver does not honor `fetchSize` while auto commit set true(default)

Unfortunately , `sql executors` in current `Nifi` versions do not have that property.

[see](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/5554) the related issue

Comment: Thanks for answering! how set this property in config of nifi?

Comment: this is a processor based property . it seems they have just added.  you can check latest version if it had reached

Comment: Helo. @yaprak. i am using the new version: 1.15.2

Comment: it seems coming next release.  by the way it comes for ExecuteSQL and ExecuteSQLRecord. i had posted before your schema edit.  you may seek some workaround such as each time fetching certain id range

Comment: Hi! using fetch size?

Comment: try it but fetch size doesnt work in current processors for postgre sql. thats the problem.   as a transient  workout, can you split your data by 1gb and carry it each time ? by using ‘additional where clause’ and with id or timestamp of your data

Comment: thanks! I believe thats work